# Jetpack Security EncryptedFile.Builder does not encrypt the file

Tags: android, kotlin, security, android-jetpack

I have a .json file named 'plants.json` located inside assets folder.
I need to encrypt it so that no one can see the contents while decompiling or reverse engineering.

```
[
  {
    "plantId": "apple_id",
    "name": "Apple"
  }
]
```

I tried to encrypt the file with [Jetpack Encrypted File](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile) .
Following is my code:

```
val secretFile = File(filesDir, "plants")

        val encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
            secretFile,
            applicationContext,
            MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
            EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
        ).build()
```

Now when I decompiled the .apk with Apk analyzer, the contents of my .json file are visible.
**PSB image:**
[image]

The official documentation states that "Jetpack Security includes an EncryptedFile class, which removes the challenges of encrypting file data."

However, No encryption was applied. Am I missing something.
**Please guide.**

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something

Jetpack Security encrypts files on the device. An asset is a file on your development machine — it is not a file on the device, and Jetpack Security does not affect assets.

> Following is my code

That code creates a file on the device, named `plants`. That is not an asset, and it is not named `plants.json`. You could look for this encrypted file via the Device File Explorer tool in Android Studio, for debuggable builds of your app.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Would you please suggest on what would be the correct approach to encrypt the asset file.

Comment: @SVK: That would be pointless. Since the decryption key and logic would exist in your app, anyone who wants to could decrypt the asset. You are certainly welcome to do it anyway, but Google doesn't offer anything to assist in that process.